# Wilted cucumber plants; watered during the afternoon

Tags: cucumbers

I left out my cucumber plants in direct sunlight after planting the transplants and came back the next day and they were wilted. I watered them in the afternoon, will they recover?

Comment: A pic of the Cucumbers & the soil they're in could help, but actually the question is written well enough that that mightn't be necessary

Answer (score 1):

They may still be ok: if watering in bright sun, generally try & avoid water on the leaves. As long as the roots didn't totally dry out they may be ok; also, maybe try shade them some, especially if they're in a small area. The temperature & humidity may also be factors, and misting them in the evening might also help. If a leaf is cleary finished, maybe remove it after carefully pinching off to keep plant from trying to send energy to it.